# Django url Routing Error

Tags: python, django, url, routes, admin

I have a very basic url router in my django project:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/?', include('customApp.urls')),
)
```

When I start the dev server and go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`, I get a `ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/` error.

Here is the content of the exception:

```
Could not import customApp.views.event. View does not exist in module customApp.views.
```

I've already tried re-ordering the urls (I have no idea how that would help, but I tried it anyway) and changing `r'^/?'` to `r'^/'`.

When I comment out the last url, the admin page works again.

Here's the `customApp.urls` code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import django.contrib.auth.views
import django.contrib.auth

urlpatterns = patterns('customApp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^rest/v1/event/add/$', 'event'),
    url(r'^rest/v1/reports/$', 'reports'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
)
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in your customApp.urls. Can you show your code? It seems that there is no view "event" in your url route.

Comment: Added the customApp.urls code.

Comment: Can you please add your customApp.views?

Comment: That's where the problem was. I had no definition for the 'event' view. Thank you, @Jingo.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple buddy. `Django cannot find customApp views`. Please ensure whatever views you have got in urls.py, it should exist.

Thanks